# How can I have a list of objects with multiple indices?

Tags: c++

I want to support a list of objects with indices. So for example:

```
struct customer
{
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  Color favorite_color;
};

template <typename T>
class indexed_list
{
  // ...
}

indexed_list<customer> allCustomers;
// ...populate the list...

list<customer> customersNamedBob = allCustomers.get_first_name("Bob");
list<customer> customersThatLikeRed = allCustomers.get_color(Colors.Red);
```

An option of course is to use SQLLite or something like that, but assuming I want to do this using simple c++ data structures, how might I go about this? Or, what is freely available already?

My plan would be to have the data stored as a `list<T>`, and then have a series of `[unordered_]map<IdxT, list<T>::iterator>`'s that bind an index to the actual value. Understandably, making this generic for any type `T` is a bit of a pain, so maybe there would be some logic that goes into a `customer_list` class that, using helper utilities inside the `indexed_list` base class, or something to that effect.  Thoughts?

Comment: Whats wrong with `map<int, list<T>*`, for example?

Comment: `find_if` is fine, but for a `list` will require a visit to each object in the list to return, so for long lists will be quite slow. If you use `set`, etc, you are basically indexing on a single element, but there are cases where you want more. There are definitely cases where you *do* want to index all fields; having an index for all isn't necessarily a bad thing :)  `map<int, list<T *>>` (I assume you meant this) would indeed work to index a single integral field, and is basically what I'm suggesting, although encapsulated in a single interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a loot at boost::multiindex

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: I expect this is the best answer; sadly, my current employer doesn't allow it's use, despite my best efforts to convince them otherwise, so I'm kinda fishing for alternatives to the one that makes the most sense :P

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using only a few of index combinations, you'd be better of with generating them as the need arises.

```
std::list<Customer> customersNamedBob;
std::copy_if(std::begin(listOfAllCustomers), std::end(listOfAllCustomers),
             std::back_inserter(customersNamedBob),
             [](const Customer& c) { return !c.name.compare("Bob"); });
```

Encapsulate the logic in a function to make it prettier and you're ready to go

```
template <class Fn>
list<Customer> query(const list<Customer>& table, Fn fn) {
    std::list<Customer> result;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(listOfAllCustomers), std::end(listOfAllCustomers),
                 std::back_inserter(customersNamedBob),
                 [](const Customer& c) { return fn(c); });
```

then:

```
customersNamedBob = query(listofAllCustomers, [](const Customer&c) { ... });
```

If speed really is the key, you can maintain several `std::list<Customer*>` sorted in different ways and then use `std::lower_bound` + `std::upper_bound` to answer the query. It isn't unlike what sql databases do.